# How do I set HttpOnly cookie in Django?

Tags: django, xss, session-cookies

How do I set HttpOnly cookie in Django?

And is it worth the effort to prevent XSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/;HttpOnly'
```

A discussion can be found here: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/bd7f562d5b938054/a229073ae836f4d2?lnk=raot&pli=1

Comment: I tried the JavaScript:alert(document.cookie); command after doing the above changes and I still get a full cookie shown within the alert. I restarted Apache as well as truncated the django_session table. No difference. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Rok: Did you log out and/or clear the existing session cookie?

Comment: New in Django 1.4 CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True will also make the csrf cookie secure, and available over https-only.

Answer (score 33):

Use

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

in settings.py

Comment: This is not part of Django 1.2 (tho it does work in the dev. version of 1.3)

Comment: It has been `True` by default since 1.4.

Comment: Documented at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY

Comment: OP asked how to set an HttpOnly cookie in django, not necessarily how to have django manage the session cookie specifically.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie

Answer (score 7):

In Django 3.0 you can set the following cookies to True in your settings.py:

- [LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#language-cookie-httponly)
- [SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY)
- [CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly)

For instances, if

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

Then your client-side JavaScript will not be able to access the session cookie.