# Getting csrf token and sessionid from response headers in react app

Tags: reactjs, django, session, django-rest-framework

We are creating some site. We have react + django rest framework.We use SessionAuthentication in django. So, we have issues with authentication. When frontend is trying to login, he get's status 200, but he can't get csrf token and sessionid from response headers, that backend hash sent. We can see them(csrf token and sessionid) in browser Network as Set-cookie values, also we see them in Postman, but not in js. Why? How can we get them?

There is part of my **settings.py**:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
    
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:5173',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:5173',
]


SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

I've tried many of settings, have tried to combine them in separate ways, but it didn't help

There is **react code**:

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export default async function login(data){
  axios.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/session/',
    data
  )
  .then( (response) => {
    console.log(response)
    // const headerKeys = Object.keys(response.headers);
    // console.log(headerKeys);
    // console.log('Set-Cookie:', response.headers['set-cookie'])
  })
}
```

This is screenshot of what we get in js[response js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVdmR.png)

This is what we see in browser[response browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH1Pp.png)

I've also seen other simillar questions, they didn't help

Answer (score 2):

You can get the csrf_token cookie.
[Here is how you can do it.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax)

If you need to get an authentication token with react, I'd recommend to use [JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) authentication for your endpoints.

It will be safer this way, to prevent XSS attacks.

You can also always just return a JSON response containing the sessionID (`request.session.session_key`)

[This might help however...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3529712/18020941)